# Split string by multiple delimiters without creating new object allocations

Tags: c#, string, split

How would I take this and make it into a method that eliminates the repetition (i.e., Don't Repeat Yourself), but also doesn't make a new boxing/object allocation—or at least as few as is feasible.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<string> SeparateLineIntoMultipleDefinitions(string line) {
    string[] splitEntries;
    splitEntries = (from str in line.Split(new[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    where str.Contains('=')
                    select str).ToArray();
    if (splitEntries.Length > 2) return splitEntries;
    splitEntries = (from str in line.Split(',')
                    where str.Contains('=')
                    select str).ToArray();
    if (splitEntries.Length > 2) return splitEntries;
    splitEntries = (from str in line.Split(' ')
                    where str.Contains('=')
                    select str).ToArray();
    if (splitEntries.Length > 2) return splitEntries;
    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Originally I tried making a method such as this:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> SplitEntries(object splitter) {
    return splitter switch {
        string[] strArray => (from str in line.Split(strArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  where str.Contains('=')
                  select str),
        string s => (from str in line.Split(new[] {s}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  where str.Contains('=')
                  select str),
        char charSplitter => (from str in line.Split(charSplitter)
                  where str.Contains('=')
                  select str),
        _ => Enumerable.Empty<string>()
    };
}
```

But alas, calling that with a `char` boxes the char into an object.

For this particular scenario I want it to try parsing `", "`, then just `','`, then just `' '`. Whereas, if I were to just call

```cs
line.Split(',', ' ')
```

I believe it would try to split something like `this=that,there x=y b=c` into `this=that`, `there`, `x=y`, `b=c`. But I don't want that extra entry `there`. (My original intention was to *keep* `there` by means of including it in the prior split, i.e., `this=that,there`, but since I was unclear, the answers did not provide a solution to accomplish that but instead *removes* the entry `there`. Therefore, I'll leave the question phrased as-is).

I would use regex, but I figure not using it would provide a more memory optimized solution (possible false premise; I'd be happy to be proven wrong). Despite what may be considered over-engineering, I am curious what the solution would be, because I have a feeling I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: Regex is sometimes more memory efficient, but the problem with Regex: You have to work with regex. It's harder to maintain and debug.On performance though, it sounds like premature optimization

Comment: you could use Regex still `Regex.Matches(strings,"[^=, ]*=[^=, ]*",RegexOptions.Compiled).Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value)`

Comment: The most memory-optimized solution would be to not allocate new strings at all. The string can be split into `Span<char>`s that index the original string. Of course, if you then need extensive processing on the results avoiding these allocations may not be worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative way to split with `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, without using `Regex`, `string.Split()`, and `System.Linq`:

---

**Code (UsingSpan):**

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SeparateLineIntoMultipleDefinitions(ReadOnlySpan<char> line)
{
    List<string> definitions = new List<string>();

    bool captureIsStarted = false;

    int equalSignCount = 0;
    int lastEqualSignPosition = 0;
    int captureStart = 0;
    int captureEnd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = line[i];

        if (c != ',' && !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            if (captureIsStarted)
            {
                captureEnd = i;
            }

            else
            {
                captureStart = i;
                captureIsStarted = true;
            }

            if (c == '=')
            {
                equalSignCount++;
                lastEqualSignPosition = i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (equalSignCount == 1 && lastEqualSignPosition > captureStart && lastEqualSignPosition < captureEnd)
            {
                definitions.Add(line[captureStart..(captureEnd + 1)].ToString());
            }

            equalSignCount = 0;
            captureIsStarted = false;
        }
    }

    if (captureIsStarted && equalSignCount == 1 && lastEqualSignPosition > captureStart && lastEqualSignPosition < captureEnd)
    {
        definitions.Add(line[captureStart..(captureEnd + 1)].ToString());
    }  

    return definitions;
}
```

---

**Code (UsingSpan_ZeroAllocation):**

```
public static (int, (int, int)[]) SeparateLineIntoMultipleDefinitions_ZeroAllocation(ReadOnlySpan<char> line)
{
    int count = 0;
    (int, int)[] ranges = ArrayPool<(int, int)>.Shared.Rent(line.Length);

    bool captureIsStarted = false;

    int equalSignCount = 0;
    int lastEqualSignPosition = 0;
    int captureStart = 0;
    int captureEnd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = line[i];

        if (c != ',' && !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            if (captureIsStarted)
            {
                captureEnd = i;
            }

            else
            {
                captureStart = i;
                captureIsStarted = true;
            }

            if (c == '=')
            {
                equalSignCount++;
                lastEqualSignPosition = i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (equalSignCount == 1 && lastEqualSignPosition > captureStart && lastEqualSignPosition < captureEnd)
            {
                ranges[count++] = (captureStart, captureEnd + 1);
            }

            equalSignCount = 0;
            captureIsStarted = false;
        }
    }

    if (captureIsStarted && equalSignCount == 1 && lastEqualSignPosition > captureStart && lastEqualSignPosition < captureEnd)
    {
        ranges[count++] = (captureStart, captureEnd + 1);
    }

    return (count, ranges);
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
var line = "this=that,there x=y b=c";

var (count, ranges) = SeparateLineIntoMultipleDefinitions_ZeroAllocation(line);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var (offset, length) = ranges[i];

    Console.WriteLine(line[offset..length]);
}

ArrayPool<(int, int)>.Shared.Return(ranges);
```

---

**Benchmark:**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 10.0.17763.1039 (1809/October2018Update/Redstone5)
Intel Xeon CPU E5-2696 v4 2.20GHz, 2 CPU, 88 logical and 88 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.101
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.1 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.60701, CoreFX 4.700.19.60801), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.1 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.60701, CoreFX 4.700.19.60801), X64 RyuJIT


|                   Method |     Mean |   Error |  StdDev |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------------------- |---------:|--------:|--------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
| UsingSpan_ZeroAllocation | 139.9 ns | 0.86 ns | 0.76 ns |      - |     - |     - |         - |
|                UsingSpan | 176.3 ns | 1.66 ns | 1.47 ns | 0.0067 |     - |     - |     192 B |
|               UsingRegEx | 218.2 ns | 2.62 ns | 2.45 ns | 0.0088 |     - |     - |     256 B |
|                UsingLinq | 339.0 ns | 3.86 ns | 3.42 ns | 0.0100 |     - |     - |     288 B |
|            UsingOPMethod | 853.0 ns | 8.80 ns | 8.23 ns | 0.0210 |     - |     - |     624 B |
```

Comment: It's a good idea to include why you think this approach is better than other solutions.

Comment: Interesting approach. I had to use `line.Slice(captureStart, captureEnd + 1 - captureStart)` instead of the `..` notation when targeting netcoreapp2.0 and net48, however. Without extensive testing, I'm getting roughly equivalent results using this and the answer proposed by @Magnetron. This appears ever-so-marginally quicker, but it could easily be within the error margin.

Comment: Added another solution with zero allocation.

Answer (score 2):

A compiled version of Regex could be used.

```
Regex.Matches(strings,"[^=, ]*=[^=, ]*",RegexOptions.Compiled)
     .Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value)
```

Here is benchmark results of Regex vs OP Method.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) overload:

```
var line = "this=that,there x=y b=c";
var spl = new[] { ", ", ",", " " };
var result = (from str in line.Split(spl, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  where str.Contains('=')
                  select str);
```

Output:

```
this=that 
x=y 
b=c
```

Comment: For the time being, this provides the quickest processing in my use-case (approximately half the overall time compared to the regex answer) when put into context. It's being called in a recursive function that eventually creates a multi-dimensional dictionary.